# What happens to %esp after a call function?

Tags: assembly, x86, att

I was doing some assembly exercises, and came up with a problem I was not able to solve. They tell me that %esp=0x08c28f6a. 
They then tell that I have a function :

funct: movw 0(%esp), %bx ;

....

ret

0x80482ae: call funct;

0x80484a4: XXXXXXX;

I don't understand what's the value of %esp and %bx after the calling of the function, and the meaning of 0(%esp) is not clear to me. I know that when the function is called, the address of the next instruction is pushed into the stack. But what content is moved to %bx?

Comment: `movw 0(%esp), %bx` takes the 2 byte value at pointed to by _ESP_ (stack pointer) and moves it into 16-bit register _BX_. When you call a function in 32-bit code _ESP_ is decremented by 4 and the Instruct pointer of the instruction after the call (the return address) is written to that memory. `call funct` is a 5 byte instruction. The instruction after the call will be 0x80482ae+5=0x80482b3 be In this case _ESP_ apparently started at 0x08c28f6a so when `funct` is called _ESP_ is 4 lower (0x08c28f6a-4 = 0x8C28F66) than before the call.

Comment: So after transfer is controlled to function `funct` the 2 bytes at memory address 0(%esp) will be the lower 2 bytes of the return address (0x82b3) which is then moved to register _BX_

Comment: In response to a comment below `movw %esp, %bx` isn't valid. ESP is a 32-bit register and _BX_ is 16-bit. This isn't allowed. If it were `movl %esp, %ebx` the current stack pointer (ESP) would be copied to _EBX_. In this case that would place the value 0x8C28F66 in _EBX_

Answer (score 0):

the return address of the function.
The code moves the value pointed by esp (offset by 0) to ebx. This is the return address.  It allows pic code to work in x86, and is used to  produce function addresses e.g.

```
call ebx+2000 ;;  call printf
```

The value of esp is not modified by reading it

Comment: Ok I think I got it but, 0(%esp) is the value on top of the stack? (return value of the function?) and what if the instruction was movw %esp, %bx?